# Add Advanced, Simple Search, listview to WCMS Backoffice explorer-tree Sap Hybris

Tags: java, xml, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have an advanced and simple search and a listview created in x-config.xml. I want to add them to the BackOffice in the WCMS section, but the file where the explorer-tree of WCMS is written (y-config.xml) is read-only. My question is, how can I append them from another file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your custom xxxbackoffice extension and in the file xxxbackoffice-config.xml from your new created extension you have to add your configuration for advance-search or what you need.